# Setting a threshold value for color segmented images to classify them

Tags: python, computer-vision

I am trying to classify images as "good" or "bad". In a given region of interest, if the region of interest painted well then it is a good image else bad. I segmented the painted parts using K means clustering then I counted pixels of painted parts. How can I set a threshold value to classify images as good or bad by using the counted pixel numbers? Or is there a better approach that I can try? I tried training simple CNN but the dataset has a big class imbalance (as I observed) and I don't have labels for images.

Comment: This seems like an extremely inefficient solution. Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I added sample images that are painted well and not painted well. I am supposed to classify them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "right" answer to your question, you are the only who could know what constitutes an acceptable paint-job. My suggestion would be to create a script which processes a big number of images you consider to be "good", append all your pixel counts to a list and then extract some statistics from that list. See what the min, max, mean values of that list are and decide accordingly what your thershold value would be. Then make the same thing for images you consider to be "bad" and see if the threshold value is always biggest than your max "bad" value. Of course the more data you have, the more reliable your result will be.

Comment: I tried setting a threshold using min-max values but couldn't get a good result. If I can't find any better solution I will return to it and try to change ROI and stuff.

Comment: In that case a single threshold value of pixel counts won't be a suitable approach for your problem. In any case you should provide more information on your problem, what you 've tried, sample images and segmented reproducable code if you want anyone to be able to efficiently help you.